# Chamar uma função especifica conforme a escolha no menu

Tags: c++

Preciso fazer um programa que simule um caixa eletrônico de um banco em C++, apresentando um menu que disponha de Depósito, Saque e Pagamento de Boletos. Como irei fazer isso? Já fiz o seguinte:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool ValidaNumeroAgencia (int agencia)
{
    if (agencia >= 100 && agencia <= 999)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
bool ValidaNumeroConta_Corrente (int conta)
{
    if (conta >= 10000 && conta <= 99999)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
float Deposito (float credito)
{
    float novo_valor;
    novo_valor = 500 + credito;
    return novo_valor;
}
int Saque (int debito, int saldo)
{
    if (debito <= saldo)
    {
        if (debito % 10)
            return debito;
    }
}
bool ValidaClienteEspecial (int saldo, int limite)
{
    int n_limite;
    if (saldo >= 10000 && ValidaClienteEspecial == false)
    {
        n_limite = limite + 5000;
        return true;
        cout << "Seu novo limite e de: " << n_limite << endl;
    }
}
float Codigo_barras(int codigo, float valor, int saldo)
{
    float n_saldo;
    if (codigo >= 100000000000 && codigo <= 999999999999)
    {
        if (valor <= saldo)
        {
            n_saldo = saldo - valor;
            return n_saldo;
        }
    }
}
float Saldo (float saldo)
    {
        cout << "Seu saldo e de:\n" "R$ " << saldo << endl;
    }

int main ()
{
    int n_agencia, n_conta_corrente, n, a;

    ValidaNumeroAgencia(n_agencia);
    ValidaNumeroConta_Corrente(n_conta_corrente);

    do
    {
        cout << "Digite o Numero da sua Conta Corrente: ";
        cin >> n_conta_corrente;
    }
    while (ValidaNumeroConta_Corrente(n_conta_corrente) == false);

    do
    {
        cout << "Digite o Numero da sua Agencia: ";
        cin >> n_agencia;
    }
    while (ValidaNumeroAgencia(n_agencia) == false);

    cout << "\n\nSelecione qual opcao deseja realizar: ";
    cout << "\n1 - Deposito";
    cout << "\n2 - Saque";
    cout << "\n3 - Pagamento de Boletos";
    cout << "\n4 - Extrato";
    cout << "\n0 - Sair\n";
 return 0;
}
```

Minha dúvida é, o q vou fazer para que o programa chame as funções de acordo com que o usuário escolher no menu? Como posso continuar o código acima?

Comment: Dê mais detalhes. O que você já fez? Onde especificamente está sua dúvida?

Comment: Já criei algumas funções como por exemplo, pedir e validar a conta corrente, o número da agência do usuário, etc... Imprimi um menu simples, olha aí:
    cout << "\n\nSelecione qual opcao deseja realizar: ";
    cout << "\n1 - Deposito";
    cout << "\n2 - Saque";
    cout << "\n3 - Pagamento de Boletos";
    cout << "\n4 - Extrato";
    cout << "\n0 - Sair\n";

E agora to tentando fazer por switch pra chamar cada uma das funções, mas nao estou conseguindo... Dá uma dica ai pfv, o q eu posso fazer. Obrigado.

Comment: Edite a pergunta acrescentando esse código e o local onde está a dúvida. Assim fica mais fácil ajudar.

Comment: Como eu coloco o código aqui nos comentários? É pq eu entrei no site tem pouco tempo... kkk

Comment: Edite a sua pergunta. Clique em `Editar` em baixo da pergunta.

Comment: Ja editei... Ajuda???

Comment: Verifique a faixa de valores passíveis de representar com um int. No caso de 32 bits o intervalo é: -2.147.483.648 a 2.147.483.647. Você define a variável codigo como int e faz o teste: if (codigo >= 100000000000 && codigo <= 999999999999).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode resolver isso basicamente com um `switch`:

```
cout << "\n\nSelecione qual opcao deseja realizar: ";
cout << "\n1 - Deposito";
cout << "\n2 - Saque";
cout << "\n3 - Pagamento de Boletos";
cout << "\n4 - Extrato";
cout << "\n0 - Sair\n";

int opcao;

// Repete até que o usuário peça para sair.
while (opcao != 5)
{
    std::cin >> opcao;

    switch (opcao)
    {
        case 1:
            // Pedo ao usuário a quantidade que será depositada.
            // E depois chama a função de deposito:
            // Exemplo:
            // Deposito(1000);
            break;
        case 2:
            // Pedo ao usuário a quantidade que será sacada.
            // E chama a função:
            // Saque(1000);
            break;
        case 3:
            // Pede os valores do boleto e chama a função Codigo_barras.
            break;
        case 4:
            // Chama a função para mostrar o extrato.
            break;
        case 5:
            // Usuário quer sair.
            break;
        default:
            // Se o usuário informar um valor inválido.
            std::cout << "Opcao invalida! Informe outro valor." << std::endl;
            break;
    }
```

---

Só uma observação: Tem algumas funções suas que nem sempre retornam um valor.
Por exemplo:

```
int Saque (int debito, int saldo)
{
    if (debito <= saldo)
    {
        if (debito % 10)
            return debito;
    }
}
```

Se o `debito <= saldo` for `false` o que a função `Saque` vai retornar?
Dá uma corrigida nisso, para que as funções sempre retornem valores esperados.

Comment: Muitoo Obrigado cara! Vlw msm...